# How can I put icon and text in select items

Tags: sapui5

I have an [`sap.m.Select`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Select) control for a list of countries and I need to put flag near everyone. How can I do it? In XML, if it's possible.

Here is my XML code:

```xml
<m:Label text="{i18n>COUNTRY}" />
<m:Select width="100px"
  fieldWidth="60%"
  class="xcuiInputNoMargin"
  enabled="{Edit>/EditOn}"
  items="{countryList>/}"
>
  <core:Item
    key="{countryList>Country}"
    text="{countryList>Country} - {countryList>Name}"
  />
</m:Select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sap.m.Select Object is restricted to display text (or Like @Jasper_07 said) icon only.

I think that the best solution for your problem is to use another object instead of your select. You can use Select Dialog and put inside whatever you want, like listItem with image.

This is an example:

```
<SelectDialog
    noDataText="No Products Found"
    title="Select Product"
    search="handleSearch"
    confirm="handleClose"
    close="handleClose"
    items="{
        path: '/ProductCollection'
    }" >
    <StandardListItem
        title="{Name}"
        description="{ProductId}"
        icon="{ProductPicUrl}"
        iconDensityAware="false"
        iconInset="false"
        type="Active" />
</SelectDialog>
```

see link [bellow](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectDialog/code/Dialog.fragment.xml)

Comment: It's good trick but i only need on select object the select dialog it's pop up list I need to use this on scroll menu

Answer (score 1):

As of UI5 version 1.62, the following controls support displaying the icon on the left side.

- `sap.m.Select`
- `sap.m.SelectList`
- And other controls based on the above mentioned ones, such as `sap.m.ComboBox`.

Here is an example:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], XMLView => XMLView.create({
 definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" height="100%">
  <Select xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" class="sapUiTinyMargin">
    <core:ListItem text="Paper plane" icon="sap-icon://paper-plane" />
    <core:ListItem text="Stop Watch" icon="sap-icon://fob-watch" />
    <core:ListItem text="Umbrella" icon="sap-icon://umbrella" />
  </Select>
 </mvc:View>`
}).then(view => view.placeAt("content"))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-xml-processing="sequential"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Keep in mind to use `sap.ui.ListItem` as an aggregation child in this case, instead of `sap.ui.core.Item`.

---

## Limitation

Currently, the `icon` property only allows resource paths from `"sap-icon://*"`. I.e. images, that are not icons such as *country flags*, are not possible. A possible workaround would be to make use of [emoji flags](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/iso3166) as `additionalText`.

Otherwise, I'd recommend to look for alternative controls as [shmoolki suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35556057/5846045).

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation of [sap.m.Select](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Select/properties)

> The URI to the icon that will be displayed only when using the
>   IconOnly type

seems limiting, but try

```
<m:Select 
  type="sap.m.SelectType.IconOnly"
  icon="sap-icon://cart">
</m:Select>
```

Comment: I know that I just want to know if it's possible to have both ( text and icon ) and not only icon or only text